# Changing CSS of Labels in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, label

I want to change css of User name and Mobile no. as that of others.
what should I change in admin.py ?

```
class orderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display= ('id','total_amount','status','user_name','notes','user_mobile')
 
    def user_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user_id.full_name 
    def user_mobile(self,obj):
        return obj.user_id.mobile_number
    
    user_name.description = 'User Name'

admin.site.register(order,orderAdmin)


 [below is the url of my screenshot image how my django admin dashboard look like][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDI0D.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Find proper selectors for thous two column labels and simply set your own css by adding this:

```
class orderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:   
        css = {
             'all': ('path/to/your/css/file',)
        }
    
    ...
```

Comment: I'm not using any addition css file ..In that case what should I go for?@Charnel

Comment: Is ther any good reason to not to use separate css file? Because other option is to explicitly set styling attribute via model form but that will make things harder to maintain.